# Duplicate the Select/Option box when user clicks add more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a simple online form I am trying to make. One of the components of the form is a drop down menu (select/option thing) showing the different employees. I have populated it in JS already as so:

```
$('#employees').append($('<option>', { value: 1, text: 'Adam' }));
```

But if the user wants to add another employee, I have a button they can click which should add another drop down the same as before. I am struggling to do this correctly. I have tried to just append the entire 'section of code' to JS like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fieldList").append("<label for='employees'>Employee</label>");
        $("#fieldList").append("<div class='select-wrapper'>");
        $("#fieldList").append("<label for='employees'>Employee</label>");
        $("#fieldList").append("<select id='employees' name='employees'>");
        $("#fieldList").append("<option>- Select Employee -</option>");
        $("#fieldList").append("</select>");
        $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
        $("#fieldList").append("</div>");

    });
});
```

But this results in this: 
[image: Duplicated the employee dropdown]

Obviously something is going wrong. The section dropdown is not interact-able. MY question then is how can I do it correctly and how can I do it better?

**HTML CODE**

```
<!-- START OF EMPLOYEE -->
<div class="field third first" id="fieldList">
<label for="employees">Employee</label>
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select id="employees" name="employees">
            <option value="">- Select Employee -</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field third first">
    <label for="wages">Amount Paid</label>
    <input type="text" name="wages" id="wages" value=""/>
</div>
```

Using template https://html5up.net/story

**EDIT**
https://jsfiddle.net/h3by56ws/ ("error": "Shell form does not validate)

Comment: You need to append entire html block. Here you are trying to append only Label and Select option. try with the parent one.

Comment: What more should I add? The block starts at the div which is 'fieldList' which is being appended to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take a look at this fiddle. You only need a few lines of jQuery to do this.](https://jsfiddle.net/xhnnsfvn/)

Keep in mind that you shouldn't have multiple DOM elements with the same ID, so you'd want to modify this.

If your HTML looks like the following, then you only need this Javascript:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
        var newSelect = $("#employees").clone();
        newSelect.val("");
        $("#select-wrapper").append(newSelect);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field third first" id="fieldList">
  <label for="employees">Employee</label>
  <div id="select-wrapper" class="select-wrapper">
    <select id="employees" name="employees">
            <option value="">- Select Employee -</option>
            <option value="1"> Bob </option>
            <option value="1"> Mark </option>
            <option value="1"> Alice </option>
            <option value="1"> Jamie </option>
            <option value="1"> Kris </option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="addMore">
 Add Employee
 </button>
</div>
<div class="field third first">
  <label for="wages">Amount Paid</label>
  <input type="text" name="wages" id="wages" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try to create a fiddle with your HTML and Javascript and see if it works there? You can post your fiddle here and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Add type="button" to the button that adds more. It's defaulting to submit the form. Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/to0b7kvo/