# Form Validation Error when cloning a select drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In reference to: [Duplicate the Select/Option box when user clicks add more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306031/duplicate-the-select-option-box-when-user-clicks-add-more)

I have a form that has a drop down menu. When the user selects to 'add more fields', a clone of the drop down menu appears. This however causes this error. I would like to know how I can go about fixing this.

[image]

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/h3by56ws/

The full error:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x7f037e0df1d0>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x7f037dec9b90>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x7f037e0df1d0>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x7f037dec9f90>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <!-- START OF EMPLOYEE -->
    <div class="field third first">
        <label for="employees">Employee</label>
        <div id="select-employees" class="select-wrapper">
        <select id="employees" name="employees">
            <option value="">- Select Employee -</option>
            <option value="1"> Bob </option>
            <option value="1"> Mark </option>
            <option value="1"> Alice </option>
            <option value="1"> Jamie </option>
            <option value="1"> Kris </option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>

</br></br>
<button id="addMore" class="button small">Add Employee</button>
<!-- END OF EMPLOYEE -->
```

**JS**

```
        $(function() {
            $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
                var newSelect = $("#employees").clone();
                newSelect.val("");
                $("#select-employees").append(newSelect);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'add employee' element is a HTML5 button element. This element has a default behavior of submit, as stated in the W3 specification as seen here: [W3C HTML5 Button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

In order to override this behavior all you need to do is add `type="button"` to the element.

See below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
    var newSelect = $("#employees").clone();
    newSelect.val("");
    $("#select-employees").append(newSelect);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
    
      <!-- Form -->
      <section class="wrapper style1 align-center">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="index align-left">
            <section>
              <div class="content">
                <form method="POST" action="">
                  <p>Select the month and the year that the expenses spreadsheet will be generated for.</p>
        

                  <!-- START OF EMPLOYEE -->
                  <div class="field third first">
                    <label for="employees">Employee</label>
                    <div id="select-employees" class="select-wrapper">

                      <select id="employees" name="employees">
                        <option value="">- Select Employee -</option>
                        <option value="1"> Bob </option>
                        <option value="1"> Mark </option>
                        <option value="1"> Alice </option>
                        <option value="1"> Jamie </option>
                        <option value="1"> Kris </option>
                      </select>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  </br></br>
                  <button id="addMore" class="button small" type="button">Add Employee</button>
                  <!-- END OF EMPLOYEE -->

                  <!-- END OF FORM -->
                  </br></br></br></br>
                  <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Generate Report" /></li>
                  </ul>
                </form>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW! That had me stumped! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Call `preventDefault` on button context:

```
$(function() {
    $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newSelect = $("#employees").clone();
        newSelect.val("");
        $("#select-employees").append(newSelect);
    });
});
```